# Tvilas keilim in winter - better in river or lake? (if no mikva around)

Tags: halacha, priorities, tevilas-keilim-dipping, utensil

In a situation where it's winter and two options are available, is it better to toivel in a river or in a lake? Which option is preferable? Both the river and lake are "medium large".

When I asked the shaila to a renowned posek in the UK about my visit to East Europe where there is no mikva and toiveling stuff there, I was shortly told that "it's ok to toivel in a river in the summer", but when I asked "but it's winter now", I was answered something like "then rather use the lake".

Recently one of my friends, (who btw works in kashrus as mashgiach) told me that a river would be preferable even in winter. So I am asking.

Comment: You might be able to use snow -- http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23448/5323

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15601/5323 (possible duplicate).

Comment: KSA 162:12 has info about this- starts with בְּעִנְיַן הַטְּבִילָה בַּנְּהָרוֹת, לְדַעַת הַרְבֵּה גְדוֹלֵי הַפּוֹסְקִים זִכְרוֹנָם לִבְרָכָה, אֵין הַטְּבִילָה מוֹעֶלֶת בַּנָּהָר אֶלָּא בִּזְמַן שֶׁהוּא קָטֹן כָּל כָּךְ, שֶׁיָדוּעַ בְּבֵרוּר, שֶׁלֹּא נִתְגַּדֵּל מֵחֲמַת מֵי גְשָׁמִים אוֹ מֵי שְׁלָגִים, כִּי מֵי גְשָׁמִים וּמֵי שְׁלָגִים אֵינָם מְטַהֲרִין אֶלָּא בִּזְמַן שֶׁהֵם נִקְוִים וְעוֹמְדִים כַּמִּקְוֶה. אֲבָל כְּשֶׁהֵם זוֹחֲלִים עַל הַאָרֶץ, אֵינָם מְטַהֲרִין, אֶלָּא מֵי מַעְיָן מְטַהֲרִין גַּם בְּזוֹחֲלִין.

Comment: lake? What kind of lake can one Tovel in?

Comment: well thats precisely my question where better to toivel - lake or river (in winter)? (BTW I think its very valid question why should anyboby down- vote such question )

Comment: @Shokhet No, it is no duplicate i am asking which is better of those two options

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on the specific river and lake? How could anyone answer this?

Comment: Very small rivers (streams) may not have enough water in one place at one time to be a valid mikvah.  In any case, have you tried asking your mashgiach friend for his reasoning?

Comment: Another facet to your question which doesn’t seem to be getting any consideration is that you seem to be talking about medium to large rivers or lakes that have frozen over at least partially. Both present unique and different elements which are an actual danger to life in regard to what is underneath the ice, point of access and your personal familiarity with the conditions. You should really be consulting with someone locally who knows the locations you are considering.

Answer (score 2):

We can't tell you about a specific river or lake without more details but can share the general laws of *tvilat keilim* in river and lakes. Note however that women should **not** immerse there without detailed instructions from their Rav <sup>1</sup>.

In summary

- **a large lake, the sea or an ocean are kosher for *tvilat keilim***
- **a smaller lake with spring water flowing in can be kosher if it hasn't rained recently and there is no concern of melted snow**
- **rivers sourced from springs can also be kosher but not if fed from melting snow - their rules are more complex and small details can be critical (e.g., the presence of a turbine upstream to produce electricity)**

[OU Kosher](https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/a-recent-halacha-yomis-linked-below-cited-rav-belsky-ztls-ruling-that-that-one-may-immerse-a-utensil-in-a-lake-provided-it-has-not-rained-in-the-last-few-days-can-you-please-cl/) brings some general rules

> The general rule is that spring water is acceptable for tevilah even
> when flowing, while rainwater and melted snow is acceptable only when
> stationary. In situations where there is a mixture of rainwater and
> spring water, we follow the majority: if mostly rainwater, the water
> must be stagnant, but if mostly spring water, the stream is acceptable
> for tevilah even when flowing.
>
> Large lakes (which are viewed as stationary bodies of water), [seas] and
> oceans are kosher for tevilah at all times, even if it had recently
> rained.

[Chabad](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4111608/jewish/Tevilat-Keilim-in-Natural-Water.htm) adds

> The water in most larger rivers is primarily sourced from springs,
> although the rivers may swell noticeably in the rain season. But my
> concern is more about mountain rivers, that flow only in the warmer
> weather, and are fed from the melting snow at the mountains' peaks.
> Melted snow has the same status as rainwater, that it is valid as a
> mikvah only when static, but not when flowing. So, you cannot immerse
> vessels in a mountain river.

See there as well as [here](https://rabbikaganoff.com/where-do-i-toivel-my-keilim/) for further details. And as always, check with your Rav for any practical ruling.

<sub>1. Practically, there are many issues which render immersing into a lake or river very delicate for women, and very often lead to non-kosher immersions. Examples are hatzitzot of earth while going down to the water, danger of currents, the fear of being seen which leads to being rushed and making mistakes, challenges of letting go of clothes, difficulties in checking the woman is ready for immersion or that it was done correctly, etc.</sub>