# When does a pot/pan need to be toveled?

Tags: halacha, mikvah-ritual-bath, tevilas-keilim-dipping, utensil

If I buy a pot/pan with intention to only use it a few times and then discard it (away on vacation and no intention of bringing it home) does it need to be toveled?

Comment: Is it a regular pan that *could* be used many times (but you're not going to), or something meant for only a few uses like a foil pan?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Rachel and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 4):

Yes it does. I have also asked this question over the years, presumably in similar circumstances. Someone goes in vacation, buys pots and pans for the duration of the vacation then wants to leave them behind. Here are the answers I received from two *rabbanim*.

If you are buying regular pots and pans, manufactured by non-Jews, they need *tevila*. If regular *tevila* in a *mikve* is not possible or convenient, two options are

1. to immerse them in a body of water kosher for that use - the sea, rivers and lakes in some cases - ask for details if you need (or you can start with [this MY question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/124140/11501))
2. to sell them to a non-Jew and borrow them back. Easiest is to give them some money (a few dollars), ask them to buy the pots/pans from you for that money then have them lend the pots/pans back to you

What you cannot do is declare the pots/pans ownerless (*hefker*) and use them anyway.